# virtual hosts in apache for *.company.com and then a separate one for www.company.com

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, server-settings

So I have a virtual server set up for www.company.com:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.company.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And then I would like to direct *.company.com to another site. How do I do it? I could think of www. and inside. being directed at specific vhosts but "the rest" directed to a generic vhost.

Apache version is 2.2.4

Comment: Although this may be useful locally, it is not best practice with regards to SEO and duplicate content http://www.wolf-howl.com/seo/wildcard-subdomains/

Comment: It depends, obviously. I always set a "catchall" domain inserting the wildcard domain in the ServerAlias directive (yes, it is a quite different and more legal case ). The reason is I don't want that my customers could think I have something misconfigured on my servers, even if they have mistyped the url inserting a wrong subdomain name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The solution at your answer**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.company.com
    ServerAlias company.com
    DocumentRoot /path1
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName *.company.com
    DocumentRoot /path2
</VirtualHost>
```

**The polite use of wildcards "catch all" domains**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain1.company.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/subdomain1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain2.company.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/subdomain2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  company.com
    ServerAlias *.company.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/primary/domain+catchall
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that the order is meaningful, the catchall domain has to be the last one.
This is particularly useful to avoid a mistyping in the client url raises an "inexistent host" error, letting the customer of your company think you are a bad server admin (not him a bad typer :P).